# How to change table border-collapse property for specific table row?

Tags: html, css

I have an example on the snippet which has table and applied border-collapse:seperate property.But I dont want second row to have this rule.Is there anyway to turn this off for specific row?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, td, th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#table1 {
  border-collapse: separate;
}

#table2 {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>border-collapse: separate</h2>
<table id="table1">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Peter</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Lois</td>
    <td>Griffin</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hello! border-collapse is for <table> only, not for <tr>. So, maybe you should remove border-collapse and work with "border-top" "border-bottom" properties of <tr> and <td>.

Comment: Same as @FFinn, Also it is a good idea to use `table, tr, td, th { box-sizing: border-box; }` so the borders are inside the element to prevent ugly tables.

Comment: I know its good idea but on a project I need to solve this only by turning that border-collapse property of for some row or overriding it

Comment: Depending on what look you are trying to get you may set "border: none;" for <td> in second row. Thus only table borders will be left in second row.

Answer (score -1):

You can use some CSS selector such as nth-child or nth-of-type to turn on/off effect for specific row.

Comment: Could u give me an example of that.I know how to do that but it didn't work for this border-collapse property